# Is Request.Cookies["value"] in c# controller some static reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies

I am having difficulty to understand some code from GitHub (I am learning angular, however this is server side code written in c#)
The code is available on GitHub [code](https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular-10-signup-verification-boilerplate)).
I can't completely understand the very first line of code `var refreshToken = Request.Cookies["refreshToken"];` Where does `Request.Cookies` come from? It is not a variable and it looks like a static call to some array `Cookies`. How does the element of that array happen to contain `"refresh-token"` item?
Could someone please explain this? (this code comes from the class derived from `BaseController`)

```
[HttpPost("refresh-token")]
public ActionResult<AuthenticateResponse> RefreshToken()
{
    var refreshToken = Request.Cookies["refreshToken"];
    var response = _accountService.RefreshToken(refreshToken, ipAddress());
    setTokenCookie(response.RefreshToken);
    return Ok(response);
}
```

Comment: It came from the class from which the controller is inherited: ControllerBase. It's not static. ControllerBase just contains useful classes like ControllerContext that represents context associated with the current request for a controller. ControllerContext contains classes such as HttpContext which contains the Request which contains the details of the request.
Request is just getter for ControllerContext.HttpRequest.Request.

Answer (score 0):

When you work in an HTTP application, .NET manages some context for you. A bunch of stuff you write, like your POST action, is provided with an HTTP context, which has properties that provide information about the request. This includes headers, cookies, etc.

When you use `Request` within an MVC controller (or some other HTTP context) you'll get access to the `HttpContext` and `Request` that relates to the specific single request. It feels like magic, but it's the framework doing the work for you.

A bit more [information on context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms972109(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: Thanks Fenton. This cookie "refreshToken" must have been sent by the client isn't it. The problem is the post method on the client for that request looks like this: `return this.http.post<any>(`${baseUrl}/refresh-token`, {}, { withCredentials: true })` so I can't see client sending this cookie.  So where is cookie "refreshToken" coming from - could it be set somewhere on the server side?

Comment: Cookies are often created server side and sent to the client. The client is then expected to hand the cookies back with each request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check other serverside codes which set the cookie,Cookie is created in serverside firstly and sent to User Agent,often stored in your browser.next time you send a request,your request may contain the cookie

you could check the codes like:`Response.Cookies.Append(....)`